Comprehensive insurance for leased car in the uk on foriegn license
I am looking into leasing a car in the UK with my new york license. I need comprehensive insurance for it, but because I have a foreign license all the insurance quotes are more than double than if I had a UK license.
Is there any way to get cheap insurance for this?

For how long do you plan to lease a car? A specialist insurer would probably be best, which companies have you got quotes from so far? uSwitch, one of the well-known UK comparison websites, mentions that Temporary insurance can be a cost-effective solution.
